# Free backup software that synchronizes folders

Tags: windows, gratis, backup

I need a **free** program that can **backup** computers with different Windows versions (XP, 2003, Vista, 7) to a network server or one computer on the network that will serve as backup.

I want it to be able to synchronize folders that I picked from each computer every few hours or instantly on folder change!

It would be nice to have an option to only synchronize **left to right** (incremental): New and modified files are copied from left to right, but deletions are not.

Comment: You might want to specify support for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shadow_Copy so that it can copy files which are in use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience, [Crash Plan](http://www.code42.com/crashplan/) works like this, and is [free for anyone backing up to their own own computers](https://www.code42.com/crashplan/features/compare/). Unfortunately, it only does continuous in the free version, but automatically makes daily backups incrementally. So far as I've tested, it's worked on [all of my versions of Windows, and claims to support Linux and Mac](http://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Getting_Started/System_Requirements).

I'm also looking for one that's free and has continuous file syncing, rather than daily, but for me this does for now.

Checklist:

- ✓ Free (for anything not on Code42's cloud and every backup location listed in your requirements)
- ✓ Backups
- ✓ XP and up
- ✗ Every few hours or more (Only daily and manual in free version)
- ✓ Keeps deleted files backed up

Answer (score 4):

Try [BitTorrent Sync](http://www.getsync.com/).  Not to be confused with the BitTorrent client.  BitTorrent Sync can transfer your files through the net, encrypts their contents by default, and supports Win/Linux/OSX/ios/android.  It will transfer files and is smart enough to understand renames and moves.  It's currently free but it may not be in the future.

[SyncThing](http://syncthing.net/) is another one to keep your eye on, but when I tried it a couple months ago it was difficult to setup and not production ready.

Answer (score 3):

[DSynchronize](http://dimio.altervista.org/eng/) is what I ended up using after trying out and comparing quite a few different backuping software. I've been using it for several years now.

It's a small program with a minimalistic design.
Still it can do pretty much anything one could wish for.
You basically pair sets of folders. This can also be done to a remote server via FTP.
There are some settings that can be changed, for example regarding whether you want them synced both ways, or whether to run a more standard back-up by copying files one-way. And plenty of more.

You can schedule automatic backups. And also add filtering conditions.
When files are deleted or replaced they can be moved to a "trash-can" folder for a while before being removed indefinitely.

But the thing that makes it outstanding in my opinion is the capacity for "Real-Time sync". DSynchronize senses within seconds whenever a file has been added/changed/deleted in any of all the folders it overlooks and then imminently performs whatever sync/back-up action it has been instructed.

Setting up a system for back-up/syncing that immediately updates a an exactly mirrored version of selected parts of your harddrive on an remote server in a different location must be the most foolproof way for keeping all your digital stuff safe.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried many (many, many) over the years and the best choice for you (for almost anyone) is [Free File Synch](http://www.freefilesync.org/)

- file and folder backup (although it's even better if the same tool supports system backups)
  yup and yup (Copy locked files (Volume Shadow Copy Service) )
- incremental backups
  not so sure, but I consider them to be A Bad Thing (anything other than a total, unencrypted, uncompressed, normal file system backup introduces possible problems when restoring)
- programmable, automatic backups (at a specific time / every night)
  yup (Automate sync as a batch job )
- supports external hard drives (as target)
  yup (that's where I keep mine)
- preferably free
  as in beer & speech (which one must mix with caution ;-)

> Key Features
>
> ```
> Detect moved and renamed files and folders
> Copy locked files (Volume Shadow Copy Service)
> Detect conflicts and propagate deletions
> Binary file comparison
> Configure handling of Symbolic Links
> Automate sync as a batch job
> Process multiple folder pairs
> Comprehensive and detailed error reporting
> Copy NTFS extended attributes (compressed, encrypted, sparse)
> Copy NTFS security permissions
> Support long file paths with more than 260 characters
> Fail-safe file copy
> Cross-platform: Windows, Linux, Mac OS X
> Expand environment variables like %USERPROFILE%
> Access variable drive letters by volume name (USB sticks)
> Native 64-bit support
> Keep versions of deleted/updated files
> Prevent disc space bottlenecks via optimal sync sequence
> Full Unicode support
> Highly optimized runtime performance
> Include/exclude files via filter
> FreeFileSync portable and local installation available
> Handle daylight saving time changes on FAT/FAT32
> Use macros %time%, %date%, et al. for recurring backups
> Case-sensitive synchronization
> Built-in locking: serialize multiple jobs running against the same network share
> ```
>
> Supported Operating Systems
>
> Microsoft Windows Microsoft Windows FreeFileSync runs natively on all
>   32 and 64-bit Windows versions:
>
> ```
> Windows 10
> Windows 8.1
> Windows 8
> Windows 7
> Windows Vista
> Windows XP
> Windows 2000
> ```