# Gratis Windows software that synchronizes individual files in real-time

Tags: gratis, windows-10, file-synchronization

Since [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/77862/cloud-backup-synch-software-that-will-follow-symlinks-so-that-i-dont-have-to) didn't get any response, I will try to achieve the same end result in a different manner.

Not to be confused with [Free backup software that synchronizes folders](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/16957/free-backup-software-that-synchronizes-folders/26885#26885).

I seek a gratis Windows 10 app which can take a list of files which can appear in one of two driectories. When one of them is updated, that update should overwrite the other. It's just your standard mirror sync, but at the file level.

---

Use case, for the curious; it is not required to read this to be able to answer the question.

I no longer trust DropBox, after it managed to overwrite the most recent copy of my code with an older version from my server, and am looking for an alternative.

Currently, I am trying [Box](https://www.box.com/).

My problem is that I have the files which I want to synch between Windows and Android strewn over multiple multiple hardrives and partitions and Box 9and others which I have looked at) want me to put them all into their single directory (tree).

My first thought was symlinks, but Box won't follow them (my other question asks for an app that will).

So, I thought that, since my sync goes

Windows files <--> box directory <--> Android

I would look for a Windows app to make sure that when a file is modified in either the Windows file structure (e.g F:\my_apps\App_x\app_X_data.ini) that the corresponding C:\box\app_X_data.ini would be updated to mirror it, and vice versa.

I can't think of another way

Comment: I had a similar issue with NextCloud a few years ago. I don't use any of these file sync services any more.

Comment: Do you have any good solution to automactically synch a few small files between Windows & Android? Just  Keepass password file, To-doo lists, etc

Comment: I switched to SVN and still use SVN. I need to sync manually, but IMHO it's worth it. Conflicts will be detected and treated properly. I don't exchange files with Android, sorry. I use SVN because IMHO it's better than Git at handling large binary files

Comment: I  also use SVN, both prefoissessionally and at home. I suppose that I could put non-code files under version control, but I would still have to have an SVN server. Also, after commiting, I would have to update the other device. I want the synch to be seamless..